# Script tag not rendering in Capybara / PhantomJS

Tags: rspec, capybara, phantomjs, stripe-payments, poltergeist

I'm using Capybara with PhantomJS to run some integration tests. Part of our test is a subscription form that uses a Stripe embedded form to render the pay button. In our test, when I run `print page.html`, this is in the output:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/subscription" 
class="plan PlusMonthly" id="plan-PlusMonthly" method="post">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"></div>
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
    <input id="plan_id" name="plan_id" type="hidden" value="3">


    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
        class="stripe-button" 
        data-key="my_test_key" 
        data-label="$9.95" 
        data-name="Subscribe" 
        data-description="Billed per month. Cancel at any time." 
        data-image="/assets/avatar_t.png" 
        data-amount="995" 
        data-email="user2@gmail.com" 
        data-allow-remember-me="false" 
        data-panel-label="Pay {{amount}} per month">
    </script>
</form>
```

However, in the live rendered version of this page, the `<form>` element also includes this:

```
<button class="stripe-button-el" type="submit" style="visibility: visible;">
    <span style="display: block; min-height: 30px;">$9.95</span>
</button>
```

So any tests that need to click the button, e.g., `within('form.PlusMonthly') {click_button('$9.95')}`, won't be able to find it and RSpec spits out this error:

```
Failure/Error: subscribe
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find button "$9.95"
```

### Versions

Capybara: 2.4.1

Poltergeist: 1.5.0

PhantomJS: 1.9.7

Comment: Have you tried running it with the chrome or firefox drivers?  It sounds like it could be an issue with the script pre-conditions; and seeing it with your eyes might help debugging.

Comment: @tmg I was using the Poltergeist screenshot command and sure enough the button doesn't render. I'm running inside Docker at the moment, so getting a driver like Selenium setup might be difficult.

Comment: Well, it's possible you just have a timing issue, which you could test with a few sleeps.  But it sounds like the script may not be working; maybe it's a stripe configuration issue?  You could also check out page.driver.network_traffic in poltergeist or see if you can't connect the remote web inspector and debug it.  Good luck!

Comment: @tmg Using network traffic, I found that some assets (like `https://s3.amazonaws.com/.../facebook_share_icon.gif` return `Status 200`, but others (like Stripe) do not: `Response URL https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js` `Status`. Interestingly, it doesn't return any status at all. I upped the sleep to 90, but no luck.

Comment: So you're saying it never retrieves that script?  Sounds like you're going to have to debug the network connection then.  Maybe start by using curl to fetch the script from inside a test and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The button is labeled '$49.95' and you're trying to click '$9.95'.  Maybe I'm missing something else I'm not seeing.

Comment: Whoops, that's a typo. But the issue is that the button doesn't even render in the test. The `<script>` tag is what renders the button and for whatever reason isn't getting executed.